# Pendulum with Oscillatory Support - A question on Lagrangian Mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator

Recently I have been attempting Morin's Introduction to Classical Mechanics (2008) but I got rather stuck on question 6.3 on the topic of Lagrangian Mechanics. Attached are the problem and the illlustrating image.

> **Question 6.3:** A pendulum consists of a mass *m* and a massless stick of length *l*. The pendulum support oscillates horizontally with a position given by x(t)=Acos(wt), see Fig. 6.10. What is the general solution for the angle of the pendulum as a function of time?

[image]

My initial thought of the question was that since the support undergoes harmonic oscillation, there must be a constant force acting on the support. For instance, a spring may be driving the motion of the support. The lagrangian calculated must include the kinetic energy of the support and the potential energy of the driving force, in addition to the motion of the pendulum.

As such, I solved the question as below:

[image]

coordinates of support: $(x, 0)$
\
coordinates of mass: $(x-l \sin \theta, -l \ cos \theta)$

$T=\frac{1}{2}M\dot x^2 + \frac{1}{2}m[\dot {(x+l \sin \theta)}^2+ \dot{(-l\cos\theta)}^2]=\frac{1}{2}M\dot x^2+\frac{1}{2}m(\dot x^2+2 l \dot x \cos \theta \dot {\theta} + l^2{\dot \theta}^2)$

$V=mgl\cos\theta+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$

$L=T-V=\frac{1}{2}M\dot x^2+\frac{1}{2}m(\dot x^2+2 l \dot x \cos \theta \dot {\theta} + l^2{\dot \theta}^2)-mgl\cos\theta-\frac{1}{2}kx^2$

When I checked the answer, however, the motion of the support is not included in the calculation of the Lagrangian L. Instead $T=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot x^2+2\dot x \cos \theta \dot {\theta} + l^2{\dot \theta}^2)$ and $V=mgl\cos\theta$. The L calculated was therefore

$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot x^2+2 l \dot x \cos \theta \dot {\theta} + l^2{\dot \theta}^2)-mgl\cos\theta$

Of course, when taking the Euler-Lagrange equations by the $\theta$ coordinates, the differential equations obtained for both cases are the same as the M and k terms have no $\theta$ or $\dot \theta$ terms, so the final answers are the same.

However, I am rather confused why the answer provided in the book allowed for the Lagrangian to be calculated for the mass alone without consideration of the support. A viable $L$ would require the total energy in the frame to be conserved. How would anyone know that movement of the support does not contribute to the energy of the mass before any calculation beforehand? Or am I missing something?

Thanks for any responses in advance.

Comment: x(t) is input not output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have confused this for a pendulum with free support. In this question, the support is made to oscillate (by whatever external force necessary) such that $x$ is always equal to $A \cos \omega t$. Therefore, $x$ is not a coordinate that you are trying to solve for. The Lagrangian only has one coordinate which is $\theta$:
$$L = L(\theta, \dot{\theta},t)$$
Your method gave the correct equation of motion simply because (1) the extra terms you added did not contain $\theta$ or $\dot{\theta}$ and (2) there is no equation of motion for $x$ in the first place.

Since $L$ depends explicitly on time through $\dot{x}$ ($\partial L/\partial t \neq 0$), energy is not conserved. This should be obvious because of the presence of the external force.

This problem can also be done using $F=ma$ if we switch into the frame of the support. In this frame, the pendulum is a simple pendulum except for an additional fictitious force of $-\ddot{x}(t) = -A \omega^2 \cos\omega t$ acting in the horizontal direction.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! However, isn't it necessary for any $L$ to satisfy energy conservation in order to satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equations?

Comment: @YaoweiFei No, that is not true. Energy is only conserved when $L$ does not depend explicitly on time.

Comment: In that case, which kinetic and potential energies do we need to include for $L$ to make sense? Initially I thought that the motion of the support contributes a potential energy function onto the motion of the particle, but I was unable to find an explicit formula. Thats why I included the motion of the support into consideration.  While I don't need to solve for x, I thought including this would prevent me from missing out potential disturbances on the motion of the particle.

Comment: @YaoweiFei I think the remark at the bottom of page 235 explains it very well. The moral is that you *can* include potentials from external forces in the Lagrangian at the cost of changing the meaning of the total energy.

Comment: Thanks for referring me to page 235 :-). I see that you could have a lagrangian that does not conserve energy - it simply changes the meaning of total energy. However, I'm rather confused to what extent could we ignore potential from external forces. lets say I'm solving a mass oscillating between two springs - could I have a lagrangian with only kinetic energy? Would it still satisfy the E-L equations?

Comment: @YaoweiFei There are two things here: (1) If there is an external force, it gets added to the right side of the E-L equations and (2) the function $x(t)$ here is considered as a force of constraint. For example, consider the [three-dimensional pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_pendulum). This is a particle that is constrained to move on a frictionless sphere of radius $R$ under gravity only. It should be obvious that there are only two coordinates in this problem, $\theta$ and $\phi$ since the radius is fixed at $R$.

Comment: @YaoweiFei We could directly write down the kinetic energy as $R^2(\dot{\theta}^2 + \sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi}^2)/2$. **However**, we could also include the radial coordinate as $r$ first. Then the kinetic energy will be $\left[ \dot{r}^2  + r^2(\dot{\theta}^2 + \sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi}^2) \right]/2$. We can then apply the constraint $r = R$.  Therefore, $\dot{r}$ becomes zero and we re-obtain the first equation. In the exact same way, we are constraining $x = A \cos\omega t$ in this problem. If we constrain $x = 0$ instead, we get the standard pendulum.

Comment: @YaoweiFei I have been talking about point (2) which applies to solving this problem in the lab frame. If we switch into the frame of the support, we get a simple pendulum with an external (fictitious) force of $-A\omega^2 \cos\omega t$ in the horizontal direction. Here is where my first point (1) applies instead, which is that external forces are added to the right side of the E-L equations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126413/discussion-between-yaowei-fei-and-vincent-thacker).